# How to implement and if/elif/else statement in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on a project, and need to fill in the "vector" months (to make a histogram : overview of the number of tweets per month). To fill in the vector month I wrote the following code:

```
numTweets = list(tweets_cleaned_panda.iloc[:,1])

months = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(0,len(numTweets)+1):

if tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Mar") or tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Apr"):
 months[0] = months[0] + 1
elif tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("May"):  
 months[1] += 1
elif tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Jun"):    
 months[2] += 1
elif tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Jul"):    
 months[3] += 1
elif tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Aug"):    
 months[4] += 1
elif tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Sept"):
 months[5] += 1
else:
 months[6] += 1
print months
```

I've tried appending .any() to the ends of the contains() statements but than it only fills month[0].

Further, I wrote the following code:

```
for i in range(0,len(numTweets)+1):
np.where(tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Mar"),
    months[0] = months[0] + 1,
       np.where(tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Apr"),
              months[0] = months[0] + 1,
                np.where(tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("May"),
                         months[1] = months[1] + 1,
                         np.where(tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Jun"),
                                 months[2] = months[2] + 1,
                                 np.where(tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Jul"),
                                         months[3] = months[3] + 1,
                                         np.where(tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Aug"),
                                                 months[4] = months[4] + 1,
                                                 np.where(tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Sept"),
                                                         months[5] = months[5] + 1,
                                                         np.where(tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains("Oct"),
                                                                 months[6] =months[]+ 1))))))))
```

But this gave the following error:

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
>     File "", line 10
>       months[0] = months[0] + 1,
>   SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Anyone that can help?

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked with tweets but if I recall correctly `created_at` can easily be converted to datetime. Can you post a sample for that?

Comment: @ayhan, further in the code, I converted the created_at into a datetiem.date format! (example is : datetime.date(2016, 3, 30)) Should I uses this format to make my calculations?

Comment: Wow, that's a heck of a monster of an expression. 

Why don't you create a list of months like

`months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]`

Then you can write something like: 
`for i in range(0,len(numTweets)+1):
     for j in months:
         np.where(tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains(j)
             months[i]+=1`

I'm not hundred percent sure that code works since I don't have pandas installed on my computer, but this would be a logical solution for me. Code would look like [this](http://pastebin.com/ipYwD5JJ)

Comment: @mutantkeyboard, When I use your code, i get the same SyntaxError as above: SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
  File "<ipython-input-41-342b1807ee6a>", line 4
    np.where(tweets_cleaned_panda['created_at'].str.contains(j), months[i]= months[i]+1)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression! :(

Answer (score 1):

pandas works very well with datetime data. Using `pd.to_datetime` function you can convert UTC formatted time:

```
pd.to_datetime("Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008")
Out Timestamp('2008-08-27 13:08:45')
```

If you first convert that column with:

```
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
```

Then you can use `.dt`  accessor for the month column:

```
df['month'] = df['created_at'].dt.month
```

To get a frequency distribution from that, all you need to do is to call `value_counts`:

```
df['month'].value_counts()
```

Note: You'll need to replace `df`  with your DataFrame's name (`tweets_cleaned_panda`).

Comment: If i run de 3de line of your code (df['month'] = df['created_at'].dt.month) , with the df change to my dataframe's name, i get the following error:'Series' object has no attribute 'dt'.

Comment: I think you are using an old version. Can you update your pandas?

Comment: We have to make our project in databricks, (In Spark 2.0). So I can't really upgrade it :(

Comment: If the second line worked fine, you can calculate the month like this `df['month'] = df['created_at'].apply(lambda x: x.month)` Keep in mind that this is not vectorized. When you have the chance, you should go with the `.dt`  version.